# Vue 3 Unit Testing - Cannot find module

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing

I'm pretty new to Unit Testing but have just started writing some in my Vue 3 application.

In the component I am testing I import some interface types from a models sub-folder like this:

```
import { ITEM } from "../models/product.models";
```

This all works fine when in the component but in my Unit Test I get this error:

```
Cannot find module '../models/product.models' from 'Product.vue'


 > 88 | import { ITEM } from "../models/product.models";
         | ^

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/index.js:259:17)
```

What do I need to do to get the test to evaluate that import correctly?

this is the config I have for jest:

```
"jest": {
    "globals": {
      "vue-jest": {
        "hideStyleWarn": true
      }
    },
    "preset": "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest",
    "testMatch": [
      "**/src/**/*.spec.[jt]s?(x)"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.vue$": "vue-jest"
    },
    "transformIgnorePatterns": [
      "<rootDir>/node_modules/(?!primevue/.*)"
    ]
  }
```

tsconfig.js

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "jest"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: What exactly is product.models? What is the extension? "import some interface type" - does this mean that you use TS?

Comment: Yes, sorry, should have mentioned that.  I'm using TS so the file is product.models.ts

Comment: What are unit tests? Is it Jest? It needs to be configured to use TS. The question doesn't mention relevant details.

Comment: Yes, (sorry again!) - using @vue/test-utils and jest.  My first few tests have been working ok - but this one is the first one that tests a component that imports some interfaces like this

Comment: I've updated the post with my Jest config from package.json

Comment: A basic setup is needed, it's not supposed to be workable without it, https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/using-with-typescript.html#configuring-typescript-for-jest

Comment: Thanks @EstusFlask that has got me somewhere but now I get the error SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' - I have googled around a bit and can't get anything to work - do you have any advice?

Comment: Depends on where exactly this error occurs. Also depends on your tsconfig, which is not shown. You may need a separate one for tests.

Comment: I've added my tsconfig to the post - the error occurs on the export from my model e.g at "{export const ITEM =" thanks for your help!

Comment: `"module": "esnext"` - this. Jest's support of ESM is disabled by default and insufficient for now. See https://huafu.github.io/ts-jest/user/config/tsConfig , likely should be `"ts-jest": {...require('./tsconfig.json').compilerOptions, module: 'commonjs' }`

Comment: Sorry I'm not exactly sure what you mean?  Do you mean I should add that exact line into my config? Also I do not have ts-jest installed?  Do I need this (my initial tests have been working so far, it's only this export from my models file that has not worked.

Comment: You need to add this line to ts-jest settings in jest config, the link shows how it should looks like. Follow https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/guides/using-with-typescript.html#configuring-typescript-for-jest , it says that ts-jest needs to be installed. These are .ts files that don't work, not a specific import.

Answer (score 0):

You should import in the test like this:

`import { ITEM } from "@/models/product.models";`

`@` is pointing to the `src` folder. Since the tests are in another folder it should work